# C# & SQL Server : how to do a sign in check

Tags: c#, sql-server

I did a sign up page with a SQL Server table and now I want to do a sign up page. How can I check if values entered exist?

Here is my code block:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSignIN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
        str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;";
        str += "Integrated Security= True";
        string userName = txtUserNameLogIN.Text;
        string password = txtPasswordLogIN.Text;
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName FROM [Table] WHERE UserName=@userName", c);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);

    }
}
```

From here I don`t know what to do...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if a username already exists you can simply check using EXISTS - something like the following:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [Table] WHERE UserName = @userName", c);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
var existingCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
if (existingCount > 0)
{
    // exists logic
}
```

**EDIT:**

Side note, but quite important - you are dealing with Disposable objects and you think about disposing them:

```
    string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    string userName = txtUserNameLogIN.Text;
    string password = txtPasswordLogIN.Text;
    SqlConnection c = null;
    try
    {
        using (c = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [Table] WHERE UserName = @userName", c))
            {  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
                var existingCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (existingCount > 0)
                {
                    // exists logic
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        // exception handling code comes here
    }   
    finally
    {
        // ensure that connection is properly closed, if database operation is done
        if (c != null && c.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            c.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void btnSignIN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
    str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;";
    str += "Integrated Security= True";
    string userName = txtUserNameLogIN.Text;
    string password = txtPasswordLogIN.Text;
    SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(str);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName FROM [Table] WHERE UserName=@userName", c);

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
            MessageBox.Show("connected");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("failed to connect");

        c.Close();

}
```